# Is it possible in numpy array to add rows with different length and then add elements to that rows in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

- Python Version: 3.7.11
- numpy Version: 1.21.2

I want to have a numpy array, something like below:

```
[
    ["Hi", "Anne"],
    ["How", "are", "you"],
    ["fine"]
]
```

But the process of creating this numpy array is not simple and it's as follows:

- `# code block 1` At the beginning we have an empty numpy array.

  *First loop:*
- `# code block 2` **row** is added in this first loop or

  in this loop we understand that we need a new row.

  *A loop inside of the first loop:*
- `# code block 3` **elements** of that row will be added in this inner loop.

Assume that:

- the number of iterations is not specified, I mean:

  - the number of columns of each row is different and
  - we don't know the number of rows that we want to add to numpy array.

Maybe bellow code example will help me get my point across:

```
a = [["Hi", "Anne"], ["How", "are", "you"], ["fine"]]

# code block 1: code for creating empty numpy array

for row in a:
    # code block 2: code for creating empty row
    
    for element in row:
        # code block 3: code for appending element to that row or last row
```

Question:

- Is it possible to create a numpy array with these steps (`code block #1, #2, #3`)?

  If yes, how?

Comment: Will you please add a sample of your expected output?

Comment: You can, but it's pointless and hard. You shouldn't be doing that or storing variable-length strings in an array. Lists are prefect for what you want though.

Comment: It is not possible to have non-rectangular numpy arrays. you will have to pad with a placeholder value.

Comment: In the example I gave, my expected output is [["Hi", "Anne"], ["How", "are", "you"],["fine"]]. @richardec

Comment: @abc. No, but you can have nested object arrays. Like I said, pointless and ugly.

Comment: @ZibaGhane. That's a list not an array. I really don't think you want arrays for this.

Comment: I do same things with lists and I wanted to compare the efficiency of using lists with numpy arrays so I asked this question. If lists are better so I will use lists. @MadPhysicist

Comment: @ZibaGhane. That makes sense. Be aware that inserting an element into an array is not as simple as for a list: you reallocate the entire data buffer and have to reassign the new object to the original name. It is much less efficient. Source: I've been doing this a while, trust me :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist. sorry, I didn't understand. So using list is better in this case than numpy array? consider my dataset is big like 9019 rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240294/discussion-between-ziba-ghane-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the nested list:

```
In [99]: alist = [
    ...:     ["Hi", "Anne"],
    ...:     ["How", "are", "you"],
    ...:     ["fine"]
    ...: ]
In [100]: alist
Out[100]: [['Hi', 'Anne'], ['How', 'are', 'you'], ['fine']]
```

Make an array from it:

```
In [101]: arr = np.array(alist)
<ipython-input-101-3fd8e9bd05a9>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  arr = np.array(alist)
In [102]: arr
Out[102]: 
array([list(['Hi', 'Anne']), list(['How', 'are', 'you']), list(['fine'])],
      dtype=object)
```

That warning tells us that we are doing something unusual, or at least suboptimal.  We can suppress the warning with `dtype=object`, but the result will be the same.

Look at the result - it's a 3 element array, where it each element is a list.  It's not a multidimensional array.  We can make an array of arrays

```
In [103]: arr1 = np.array([np.array(el) for el in arr], object)
In [104]: arr1
Out[104]: 
array([array(['Hi', 'Anne'], dtype='<U4'),
       array(['How', 'are', 'you'], dtype='<U3'),
       array(['fine'], dtype='<U4')], dtype=object)
```

Sounds like you want to duplicate this list constructor with arrays:

In [107]: al = []

```
     ...: for row in alist:
     ...:     al1 = []
     ...:     for el in row:
     ...:         al1.append(el)
     ...:     al.append(al1)
     ...: 
In [108]: al
Out[108]: [['Hi', 'Anne'], ['How', 'are', 'you'], ['fine']]
```

But there are several problems.

There isn't a simple "empty" array; arrays can have a shape like (0,) or (0,3) or (3,0,3) etc.

Arrays don't have a simple and fast `append`.  `np.append` does not qualify.  Any attempt to "grow" an array results in making a new array with a full copy.  List append just adds a pointer to an object that's designed to grow.

While `numpy` can make string dtype arrays (as in [104]), it does not have special string handling code.  You must still use python string methods to manipulate those strings.

Math on object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss and slower than math on numeric arrays.  Essentially it takes place at list-comprehension speeds.

`numpy` is designed for fast numerical work on multidimensional arrays.  Think things like matrix multiplication, addition.  Even when used as a stepping stone to machine learning the arrays need to be numeric and "rectangular".  Ragged lists cannot be used for ML.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy arrays are not optimised for inconsistent dimensions, and therefore not good practice. You can only do this by making your elements objects, not strings. But like I said, numpy is not the way to go for this.

```
a = numpy.array([["Hi", "Anne"], ["How", "are", "you"], ["fine"]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I'm a beginner to python. So using lists is better and more efficient in this case?

Comment: Yeah probably, if you're not going to run very large programs you can do most stuff in lists which are much more flexible

Comment: my dataset is big and have 9019 rows, so in this case, is it better to use lists or numpy array is better? @SuperPineapple

Comment: you'll probably be okay using lists. 9019 is not that big